# How to prevent Firefox from redirecting to OpenDNS's "website-unavailable.com"?

Tags: firefox, redirection, opendns

I'd like to get Firefox to work with OpenDNS, but still retain Firefox's standard behaviour when typing something on the location bar.

Before I set up things to run OpenDNS, if I typed `google` on the location bar, it'd redirect to `www.google.com`. Now, it redirects me to [`www.website-unavailable.com`](http://www.website-unavailable.com/main?wc=EWJmGxd5DRhfBBB3GAkDFA%3D%3D&url=google&w=1366&h=647&ifc=0), showing me search results for the word `google`. It also retains this behaviour whenever I type a single word on the location bar.
The behaviour is slightly different when I type more than one word, but still not what I expected: it searches in Google for whatever I type. For instance, if I type `google maps` it gets me [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb).

Before I had set OpenDNS, if I typed a single word it'd either redirect me to the site at once, or if there was no clear match, it'd show me search results on Google.
Whenever I typed more than one word, it'd most likely redirect me to a site too (for `google maps` it'd get me directly to Google Maps' page), unless, once again, there was no clear match.

I've checked `about:config`, and everything (both `keyword.enabled` and `keyword.URL`) seems fine according to [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/795446#answer-152292).

Is there any way I could get Firefox back to its old behaviour and also retain OpenDNS?

Comment: Why are you using OpenDNS at all? I stopped using OpenDNS for this exact reason, they're giving back bogus answers in various situations. I started using Google's public DNS servers, the famous 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and never looked back.

Answer (score 2):

OpenDNS is doing something called a wildcard search return, and is therefore pre-empting Firefox from doing what you expect it to.

You maybe able to turn this off:
http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_8649767_disable-opendns-redirecting.html

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to make the trick.

Comment: Perhaps you cannot change this behaviour from OpenDNS with their free service.

Comment: I was able to do what the link you provided said. It just didn't change any behaviour.

Comment: It may take time for setting to propagate out to their DNS servers.  Or their free service may not honour that setting in some way.  If you are using Windows, you could try ipconfig /flushdns.  Just as an experiment, try using Googles DNS servers, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 which I would expect work as you would like.  Quite simply, you may not be able to disable the wildcard return feature of OpenDNS.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately there are Firefox add-ons which can get rid of the 'website-unavailable.com' redirect (including for single word searches) - without needing to create an OpenDNS account or specify your IP to them on their website.

Try one of the following extensions:

1. [InstantFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/) (no restart) - to configure it as desired enable the "Standard search without shortcuts" feature up the top of the main settings panel and set your desired search engine in its 'edit' window also.
2. [Omnibar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/omnibar/) - requires restart but works right out of the box for basic single keyword searching going straight to the search engine that you set within Firefox itself. Also has options to tame it down and tweak things as desired.

It's true these address bar add-ons may bring a little extra baggage than 'simply removing this redirect' over the default firefox address bar itself and may also change the behaviour of some aspects of it - but in the end you may actually prefer its subtle changes (e.g. I noticed Omnibar seems to remove the 'Switch to Tab' feature, but I actually like that, I've been finding Switch to Tab very annoying!).

But in either case - it *does* take control of Firefox's address bar enough to override OpenDNS' annoying hijacking browser-side, where setting "keyword.url" in `about:config` isn't cutting it for all scenarios.